# x,y parameters in plot() to be treated as RGB or 2D scalar in imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

in the description of [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-plot)  it can be found that to plot data according to the parameters provided in terms of *x, y, z*; Depending on the dataset type we want to plot. The goal of this program is to plot data using [`matplotlib.Axes.axes.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-imshow) to get images.

How could I do it taking into account that the data set provided is of different `x,y` arrays and that **`imshow`** can only receive an *array-like* **RGB** or **2D scalar data** as parameter?

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

num_series = 1000
num_points = 100

x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, num_points) 
Y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(num_series, num_points), axis=-1)

ax.plot(x[:100],Y[:100])
#ax.imshow(x[:100],Y[:100]) # raises ValueError: array([[. . .]])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cold use `pcolormesh` for the plotting.
Does something like this work?

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

num_series = 1000
num_points = 100

x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, num_points) 
y = np.arange(num_series)
Z = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(num_series,num_points), axis=-1)

ax.pcolormesh(x,y,Z)

plt.show()
```

Which results in the following plot:

[image]

**EDIT**
Calling `imshow` should work as well, this is how that looks like (it scales the width and height of the picture according to the dimensions of the matrix).

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

num_series = 1000
num_points = 100

x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, num_points) 
y = np.arange(num_series)
Z = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(num_series,num_points), axis=-1)

ax.imshow(Z)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the use of `pcolormesh` is valid since it works with the data *x, y, z*. But it would be possible to generate from `pcolormesh` or from *x, y, z* an array that is an image to be able to be graphed using as parameter on **`imshow`**

Comment: I am not sure I understand that comment exactly, but you should also be able to call `ax.imshow(Z)` in my script above. Does that help?

Comment: The variable `Z` is calculating a random *array values* of `num_series` and `num_points`, without `x,y` data, generally I want to get the same plot result from **`pcolormesh`** but using **`imshow`**

Comment: I made an update using `imshow`.